# Do plastic shoes electrically insulate people from the ground?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, everyday-life

I've read on the Internet that wearing plastic shoes doesn't allow electric charges we collect from our environment (PC, TV, appliances) to be earthed.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: and rubber soles (like found on most shoes) would do the same

Comment: I think the problem is more about the friction between the rubber/polyurethane soles and the floor that builds up static charge.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is on topic here, but let's see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reasoning is correct as long as electric potential you're touching isn't very-very high and the plastic is normal (Conductor plastic has been invented).

Electricity flows from higher potential to lower potential via a conductor. Earth is zero potential and Human body is a good conductor which allows electricity flow when we touch anything at positive potential with naked feet. Normal plastic, rubber etc are bad conductor of electricity which disconnects higher potential from lower one. But, remember, a bad conductor can't hold if potential difference is very high (meaning, the point you're touching has very-very high potential).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your exhaustive answer but does it mean that using appliances I accumulate charges in my body when I dress plastic shoes? :)

Comment: @Surfer No. Charges can't enter in the body when its not connected with lower potential.